# Angular-UI-Router nested views in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-ui-router

I am having trouble with Angular UI Router displaying when using nested views in IE8. It appears to be able to go about 2 layers deep, and then after that I get the following error in my console:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$compile/tplrt?p0=message&p1=<ui-view class=ng-scope>
```

The html template of the state is loaded/pulled successfully, but this error halts execution before the controller for the state is called.

Unfortunately I was not able to duplicate this issue in jsFiddle, so I'll attempt to illustrate the issue here.  The structure of the site looks like the below:

```
Main page (contains sidebars and title bars that stay constant)-----------------------
|
|    <div ui-view>-Filled with abstract 'User' state html when user.list state called-   
|    |
|    |    <div ui-view="filters">-Search filters displayed here-----------------------
|    |    <div ui-view="list">-Results from the search shown here---------------------
|    |    <div ui-view="details">-If edit/add is clicked, show edit user page---------
|    |    |   The template for the 'details' view is just "<ui-view/>"
|    |    |   This is the page that is not displayed due to the template error
|    |    |___________________________________________________________________________
|    |________________________________________________________________________________
|_____________________________________________________________________________________
```

Here is what the `states.js` looks like:

```
.state('user', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/user',
    templateUrl: '/admin/user/user.html',
    controller: 'userController'
})
.state('user.list', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        'filters': {    templateUrl: '/admin/user/user.filter.html',
                        controller: 'userFilterController' },
        'results': {    templateUrl: '/admin/user/user.list.html',
                        controller: 'userListController' },
        'details': {    template: '<ui-view/>'}                             
    }
})
.state('user.list.add', {
    url: '/add',
    templateUrl: '/admin/user/user.add.html',
    controller: 'userAddController'
})
.state('user.list.edit', {
    url: '/{userId}',
    templateUrl: '/admin/user/user.edit.html',
    controller: 'userEditController'
});
```

This only occurs in IE8, and displays fine in IE9+ and other modern browsers. It should be IE8-compatible.

EDIT:  I have discovered the issue.  The problem was due to a directive that was included within the HTML of the child state (user.list.edit and user.list.add).  This directive had 'replace: true' configured, which was causing IE8 to throw the template error.  This directive was also used in the parent state, but did not cause an issue there.  Editing the directive to not require the replace resolved the issue.  Hopefully this will help anyone else who stumbles across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found this exact error can also be caused by incorrectly closed tags deep in a template's DOM tree ex:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div></strong> <!-- ERROR! -->
    </div>
</div>
```

use something like this to prevent this from happening at build time:

https://github.com/nikestep/grunt-html-angular-validate